# Learn how to make cool design in Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, blend

My skills in designing UIs is very poor. I've never used Blend before to create cool designs. Here I've found a great tutorial: http://www.kirupa.com/net/intro_blend_animation_pg3.htm. This for me not enough. I want to learn more on this topic. I've also serached on MSDN/Microsoft for some videos or HowTos. There is nothing there. Do you know some good ressources like blogs? For short: I want to learn how to designing in Blend.

Comment: I'd also recommend reading some books on usability, it's no good having the world's prettiest UI if it's a nightmare to use.

Comment: +1 its the user experience that matters more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be quite a bit of material here.

http://sandrinodimattia.net/blog/post/Complete-Expression-Blend-and-Silverlight-5-day-OnRamp-training-course-All-videos-all-assets-download-packages-in-one-place.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Dig [Microsoft's portal for Expression](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc136522.aspx). Plenty of videos and links to tutorials in there.

`<flippant>`If that's not enough, consider taking some graphic-design courses? :)`</flippant>`

Answer (score 1):

I know that a book is not what you are exactly looking for, but foundations book is a good starting point. [http://www.amazon.com/Foundation-Expression-Blend-4-Silverlight/dp/143022973X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022973X)